# Problems view is not showing error & warning icons in my rcp product

Tags: icons, eclipse-rcp

I have added eclipse problems view in my rcp application(Eclipse Luna). While adding the IMarker to the resource it is successfully adding the marker(error/warning) to the resource.

But while if i try to open the problems view it is showing all the warnings & errors but it is not showing icons.

Answer (score 1):

The Problems view is expecting a number of shared images to have been set up by the RCP Application Advisor. This is normally done by `IDEWorkbenchAdvisor` but you will have to do something similar in your advisor.

The code that does this looks something like:

```java
Bundle ideBundle = Platform.getBundle(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.IDE_WORKBENCH);

declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle,
            IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PROBLEMS_VIEW,
            PATH_EVIEW + "problems_view.png", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle,
            IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PROBLEMS_VIEW_ERROR,
            PATH_EVIEW + "problems_view_error.png", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle,
            IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PROBLEMS_VIEW_WARNING,
            PATH_EVIEW + "problems_view_warning.png", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle,
            IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PROBLEMS_VIEW_INFO,
            PATH_EVIEW + "problems_view_info.png", true); //$NON-NLS-1$


private void declareWorkbenchImage(Bundle ideBundle, String symbolicName,
        String path, boolean shared) {
    URL url = FileLocator.find(ideBundle, new Path(path), null);
    ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    getWorkbenchConfigurer().declareImage(symbolicName, desc, shared);
}
```

Note: This uses several **internal** classes and is consequently not part of the official Eclipse API and may be changed by Eclipse without notice.

Comment: Hi, i tried with above mentioned code, now problem view icon was showing for the view. But not for the warnings & errors which are listed in the view. It is showing as red colour square box icon for listed warnings and errors.

Comment: Well you are going to have to search around in the Eclipse source to identify exactly which images it requires.